# 3d Navbar That Rotates

Tags: css, transform, transition, perspective

I'm trying to create a 3d navbar using pure CSS with transforms, transitions and perspective.

Here is my code:

```css
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
   background: transparent;
 }
 
 .navbar-perspective {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-perspective: 1100px;
   -moz-perspective: 1100px;
   perspective: 1100px;
   -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 0;
   -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 0;
   perspective-origin: 50% 0;
 }
 
 .navbar-perspective > div {
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   text-align: justify;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   height: 50px;
   font-size:20px;
 }
 
 .navbar-primary {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   z-index: 2;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
   transform-origin: 0% 100%;
 }
 
 .navbar .navbar-secondary,
 .navbar .navbar-tertiary {
   background-color: #bfbfbf;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
   -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
   transform-origin: 0% 0%;
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
   transform: rotateX(-90deg);
   -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
   transition: top 0.5s;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
 }
 
 .navbar .navbar-tertiary {
   background-color: #b3b3b3;
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-primary {
   height: 50px;
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-primary .navbar-primary {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
   transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-primary .navbar-secondary,
 .navbar-rotate-primary .navbar-tertiary {
   top: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
   transform: rotateX(-90deg);
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-secondary,
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary {
   height: 50px;
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-secondary .navbar-primary,
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary .navbar-primary {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
   transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-secondary .navbar-secondary,
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary .navbar-secondary {
   top: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
   transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-secondary-fallback .navbar-primary,
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary-fallback .navbar-primary {
   display: none;
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary .navbar-secondary {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
   transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
 }
 
 .navbar-rotate-tertiary .navbar-tertiary {
   top: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
   transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-100%);
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

 <nav id="navigation-bottom" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="navbar-perspective">
   <div class="navbar-primary">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#navigation-bottom').attr('class','navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-rotate-secondary')">Rotate To Face 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-secondary">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#navigation-bottom').attr('class','navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-rotate-tertiary')">Rotate To Face 3</a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-tertiary">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#navigation-bottom').attr('class','navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-rotate-primary')">Rotate Back To Face 1</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

I've got the first two faces to rotate properly using a 3d effect, but the third face does not look right. You will notice as you rotate from second to third that the top does not rotate correctly and looks flat.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcb6kerq/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, thank you to all that commented and answered to this question, especially Josh!

Josh, your example works perfectly for browsers that support preserve-3d. The update you posted without preserve-3d appears flat on IE so it was still not perfected for all browsers.

After three days of headaches, I realized the problem. The origin of the sides was not being set correctly. The sides need to rotate around a point that is half way in on the Z axis.

Once I've updated the origin to :

```
transform-origin: 25px 25px -25px;
```

Once this was correct, all you really need to do is update the rotation of the object. No need to use any transformation of the X,Y,Z coordinates.

Here's the fiddle and the solution for a 3D Navigation bar that rotates and works for all browsers including IE10+.

http://jsfiddle.net/tx0emcxe/

Comment: Josh, your example on IE has no perspective. Its like looking at a 3D object from the front. When sides rotate, the sides don't move towards the middle, thus appearing flat.

Comment: @misterManSam - You're absolutely correct in that and I'm well aware.  However, I feel a little miffed about the asker's demeanor and insistence that my answer was somehow incomplete, even in his own accepted answer.  Not concerned about the bounty being awarded so much as that.  In the interest of not being unsupportive of the community here, I've removed my comments.  Point taken.

Answer (score 7):

## [Fiddle with a flipping box](http://jsfiddle.net/L3724xLh/1/)

This is vastly different from where you started, but let me post my CSS and show you the fiddle, and then I'll edit in a longer explanation of how and why this works:

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
    <nav id="nav-box" class="show-front">
        <div class="front">
            <a href="#">Show Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a href="#">Show Back</a></div>
        <div class="back">
            <a href="#">Show Top</a></div>
        <div class="top">
            <a href="#">Show Front</a></div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

#nav-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#nav-box div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

#nav-box .front  { transform: rotateX(   0deg ) translateZ( 25px ); background-color: #ccc; }
#nav-box .back   { transform: rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 25px ); background-color: #ccc; }
#nav-box .top    { transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 25px ); background-color: #ccc; }
#nav-box .bottom { transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 25px ); background-color: #ccc; }

#nav-box.show-front  { transform: rotateY(    0deg ); }
#nav-box.show-front .bottom { background-color: #a0a0a0; }
#nav-box.show-front .top { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
#nav-box.show-back   { transform: rotateX( -180deg ); }
#nav-box.show-back .bottom { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
#nav-box.show-back .top { background-color: #a0a0a0; }
#nav-box.show-top    { transform: rotateX(  -90deg ); }
#nav-box.show-top .front { background-color: #a0a0a0; }
#nav-box.show-top .back { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
#nav-box.show-bottom { transform: rotateX(   90deg ); }
#nav-box.show-bottom .front { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
#nav-box.show-bottom .back { background-color: #a0a0a0; }
```

## Explanation of the HTML/CSS

**Setting up our box**

You started thinking about this the wrong way, I hate to say.  You approached this as *"How can I treat these four sides like a box"* rather than *"How can I make a box in CSS?"*

So let's learn how to make a box.

First, we establish a `box` container.  Since this is a navigation box, let's call it `nav-box`. All the transforms we apply (save for the shading, which we'll get to later) will be done on our `nav-box`.

The rules on our `nav-box` will determine how it behaves as an object.  Let's discuss two in particular: `transform-origin` and `transform-style`

`transform-origin` defaults to center center, but I wanted to call it out here.  This is basically going to tell our box: *Hey, we need you to pivot around your absolute center*.  If we set this up as `transform-origin: center bottom' it would look like the box is spinning around its bottom edge.`  center top` and it would spin around its top edge.  I don't think that's what you want, though.

`transform-style` needs to be set to `preserve-3d`.  What this does is instruct the browser to not fuss with the elements with `transform` underneath it.  Other options include `flat` which tells the browser to ignore rotates underneath it.  The reason we want to set `preserve-3d` on our `nav-box` here is to ensure the `transforms` we applied to the box sides are preserved when we `transform` the parent.  Neat stuff, huh?

**Setting up our sides**

We're setting our sides as children of our `nav-box` and just positioning them in the order that they should be in using `rotateX`:

- `0` rotation for the front
- `180deg` for the back
- `-90deg` for the bottom
- `90deg` for the top

We could also set a left and right side right now with `.left { transform: rotateY(-90deg); } .right { rotateY(90deg); }`.  Note that we used the `Y` axis for those two examples.

Secondly, we set a `translateZ` value of `25px`.  So what the hell is this doing?  It's telling our boxes they need to move `25px` from the center of the parent relative to their respective rotations.  Why did we choose `25px`?  Because it's exactly half the height of each of our boxes.  This means that it will flush up nicely with the sides at either edge.

**And then the fun part:**

We shade the boxes based on their position and what is facing the screen.  The background colors are relative to what side of the box we're showing with `show-front`, `show-back`, etc.  The side on the bottom gets darker, the side on the top gets lighter.  I just liked that – totally not necessary to accomplish this task but makes it look a little more realistic.

Hope that helps!

---

## Update for IE

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3724xLh/3/)**

So, there's not much pretty about this once we get through fixing it up for IE, but here it is.  All `preserve-3d` is doing is applying the transforms for you when we rotate a container, instead of flattening them.  If we can't use `preserve-3d`, we have to calculate based on the amount of total rotation.

This solution does that.  I won't go as in-depth on this one, rather than to highlight how much more JavaScript this requires, and to highlight the `.rewind` class:

```
#nav-box.rewind div {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Because we have to manually rewind this solution, we'll have to prevent the z-index reordering to be applied at the wrong times.  That's where `backface-visibility` comes in.

**[Example showing depth in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3724xLh/9/)**

**[Another example without the need for the `rewind` class](http://jsfiddle.net/L3724xLh/8/)**

Hope that solves **IE** for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not work on IE because you are using the preserve3d property. The trick is to NOT use that property.

Comment: @Armin - Check the edit.  I gave you an IE eligible fix.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're getting at with the perspective being flat, it's very much not flat.  Try reducing the `perspective` number and setting a `perspective-origin`, and it'll be very obvious.

Comment: The example freaks out if you decide to click on a link while it's rotating back.

Comment: @porglezomp - Hadn't thought of fixing for that.  Which example are you referencing?