# 3D Box Shadow effect

Tags: css, css-shapes

So I know how to do a basic box shadow with CSS3. You can see that in the top of the graphic below.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is a 3D box shadow, as shown in the bottom of the graphic below.

Any ideas on how to do this with CSS3 box shadows?

[image: 3D box shadow effect]

Comment: Generally, I have seen this effect created through multiple box-shadows.

Comment: Any reason you're constraining it only to box shadows instead of the several 3D-specific CSS3 props that have been introduced?

Comment: @JoshBurgess enlighten me! As long as it has the same browser compatibility I'm all ears!

Comment: Well, there are several examples out there of creating 3D elements using depth-based CSS.  Here's a recent answer I had on another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986830/3d-navbar-that-rotates/27046256#27046256, and here's a great resource for faux-physical objects on the web: http://www.creativebloq.com/3d/how-create-impressive-3d-graphics-css3-21410672

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately box shadows are effectively just flat layers. However you can apply multiple box shadows to create this effect.

```
.box-shadow-3d{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #999,
                2px 2px 0px #999,
                3px 3px 0px #999,
                4px 4px 0px #999,
                5px 5px 0px #999,
                6px 6px 0px #999;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use pseudo element for as shadow

```css
div {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
div:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translatey(100%) skewx(45deg);
}
div:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%) skewy(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a real 3D shadow using `perspective` and pseudo-element `:before`.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
.foo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  persepctive: 1000px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.foo .box {
  transform: rotateY(-40deg);
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}
.foo:before {
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 375px;
  background-color: grey;
  transform: translateX(215px) translateY(2.7px) rotateY(55deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can stack the horizontal/vertical offsets of several box-shadows, each slightly bigger than the previous one. The more shadows you add, the more pronounced the effect. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6jpvgo8/1/) example.

```
div {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow:  0 01px gray,
                 01px 0 gray,
                 01px 02px gray,
                 02px 01px gray,
                 02px 03px gray,
                 03px 02px gray,
                 03px 04px gray,
                 04px 03px gray,
                 04px 05px gray,
                 05px 04px gray,
                 05px 06px gray,
                 06px 05px gray;
}
```

Comment: I would have chosen this answer but not sure why there is alternating shadows here? It kind of gave a jagged edge feel. Not as smooth and straightforward as @BurpmanJunior's answer.

Comment: This method is more useful than BurpmanJunior's answer when you want to apply different color shades to each side: e.g. `lightgray` to the right and `darkgray` below.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with these two options, so I adapted some diagonal gradients from Lea Verou's excellent book *CSS Secrets*.  I thought about creating a gradient inside a right and bottom border via `border-image`, but that property does not allow edge targeting, à la `border-right-image`, etc.

So, I settled on using a pseudo element with two truncated corners, which  seems to work pretty well.  You have to be careful to adjust the width of the gradient to be 1.414 the size of half the padding, since this would be the diagonal of a square (square root of two).  Also, since that's a pseudo element, be careful of the right placement.  Interested to hear what you folks think.

```css
div {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 1em 1.2em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #111;
  font: 150%/1.2 Georgia, Palatino, Times, serif;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 1.42em; /* (square root of gradient position) */
  background: #000; /* Fallback if not supported */
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 2em, #000 0) top right,
    linear-gradient(#000, #000) padding-box bottom right,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 2em, #000 0) bottom left; 
    /*I have avoided adding -webkit-, -moz and -0 prefixs for linear-gradient.  You may put them in later to be extra safe*/
    background-size: 50% 50%; /* There is no reason to paint the upper left quadrant, so I didn't. */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;  box-sizing: content-box; 
    /*  Many people use border-box as default these days. Unfortunately, the box cannot be sized using border-box settings with the combination of padding in ems and percentages.  So this is reset to content-box, just in case.   */
    z-index: -1; /* To keep the shadow behind the div*/
```

```html
<div>This is a short sentence to demonstrate that our little div is responsive.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little implementation, inspired by @Vitorino fernandes, in [`stylus`](http://stylus-lang.com)...

```
offset = 10
border = 3
.offsetbox
   margin offset
   padding offset
   text-align center
   box-shadow inset 0 0 0 unit(border,px) black
   background white
   display inline-block
   position relative
   &:after,
   &:before
      content ''
      background black
      position absolute
   &:after
      width 100%
      height offset
      transform translatey(100%) skewx(-45deg)
      right (offset/2)
      bottom 0
   &:before
      height 100%
      width offset
      transform: translatex(-100%) skewy(-45deg)
      left 0
      top (offset/2)
```

[image]

Comment: hi, can you add a border radius top right 80px and bottom left 80px, and the shadow should follow the bottom left radius also? i also having a hard time doing this, thank for your code

Answer (score 0):

I added some clip paths to [@Vittorino fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4025556/vitorino-fernandes) code, to avoid white space between pseudos and make it sharper.
I added some 1px adjustments to avoid bad svg rendering problems.

You can use the variable called shadow-dimension to set the shadow width and height.

I Put it on a codePen:
https://codepen.io/silviamalavasi/pen/poVWeMY

```
:root {
    --shadow-dimension: 20px;
    --blue: #0039a6;
}
.box-container {
    position: relative;
 }
.box-container>div {
    border: 2px solid var(--blue);
}
.box-container>div:after, .box-container>div:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: var(--blue);
    position: absolute;
}
.box-container>div:before {
    width: calc(var(--shadow-dimension) + 1px);
    height: calc(100% +  100px + 1px);
    left: calc(var(--shadow-dimension) * -1);
    transform: skewy(-45deg);
    top: calc(0.5*var(--shadow-dimension));
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% calc(100% - 100px - 2px + var(--shadow-dimension)), 0% calc(100% - 100px - 2px));
}
.box-container>div:after {
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    height: calc(var(--shadow-dimension) + 1px);
    left: calc(-0.5*var(--shadow-dimension) - 100px);
    bottom: 1px;
    transform: translateY(100%) skewx(-45deg);
    clip-path: polygon(100px 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, calc(100px + 2px) 100%);
}
```

Comment: This results in a 404 error?

Comment: Strange. I change the answer with the correct url.