# Slantic shadow of circle in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make this kind of shadow of circle in CSS?

[image]

Comment: same logic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298934/3d-box-shadow-effect/

Comment: The question you guys are linking to isn't the same in my opinion. That one is solved with multiple backgrounds, while this would require a different approach to achieve the gradient.

Comment: @C1one_38, since they closed it... see here for a solution to this question. https://jsfiddle.net/cm9q26mv/

Comment: http://codepen.io/tholex/pen/BjRmOq

Comment: thank you all for a quick response!